# split string using regex for time formats in java

Tags: java, regex

I have a String which could contain any of the below two time formats:

- 1:46 PM
- (2:49:02 PM)

I want to split this string in java using regex.

example:
`String str="hello ram, you logged in at1:46 PM we welcome you. Hello ram you logged out at(2:49:02 PM) see you again."`

expected output using `split` using `regex` should be:

`hello ram, you logged in at`

`1:46 PM we welcome you. Hello ram you logged out at`

`(2:49:02 PM) see you again.`

what regex should I use in this case. I want the spliting of text in both time formats in new line. guide me.

Comment: `(` is not really part of timestamp

Comment: Are there any whitespaces between the timestamps?

Answer (score 1):

You could come up with something like:

```
(?<tsp>\d+(?::\d+)+)\s[AP]M
# Looks for a digit (minimum 1)
# followed by at least one (or multiple pairs) of ":" and another digit
# this pattern is captured in a named group called tsp
# ... which in turn is followed by a whitespace and "AM" or "PM"
```

See a [demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/xO8yH2/2).

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this in Java:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(
  "(?im)((?:^|\\(?\\d+(?::\\d+)+\\s+[AP]M\\)?).*?)(?=\\(?\\d+(?::\\d+)+\\s+[AP]M\\)?|$)");

Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

while (m.find() {
   System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fR9eQ9/1)

**Output**

```
hello ram, you logged in at
1:46 PM we welcome you. Hello ram you logged out at
(2:49:02 PM) see you again.
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex splits the input as required:

```
(?=\(\d\d?:\d\d:\d\d [AP]M\)|\d\d?:\d\d [AP]M [^)])
```

See [live regex demo](http://rubular.com/r/Y9tPSPqkTL).

---

Some test code:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    String str="hello ram, you logged in at1:46 PM we welcome you. Hello ram you logged out at(2:49:02 PM) see you again.";
    Arrays.stream(str.split("(?=\\(\\d\\d?:\\d\\d:\\d\\d [AP]M\\)|\\d\\d?:\\d\\d [AP]M [^)])")).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Output:

```
hello ram, you logged in at
1:46 PM we welcome you. Hello ram you logged out at
(2:49:02 PM) see you again.
```